# How to subset using partially matching strings?

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to isolate participants who are categorised as either NJS or ELJ, followed by a number eg NJS1, NJS2, ELJ8, ELJ25 etc. I remember that there's a symbol I'm looking for which means "selected cells contain "XYZ" followed by anything", allowing my participants to be separated into the two groups. I have tried the following, to no avail.

```
NJSBio = subset(biography, biography$`L1(s)` == "NJS#")
//
NJSBio = subset(biography, biography$`L1(s)` == "NJS?")
//
NJSBio = subset(biography, biography$`L1(s)` == "NJS*")
```

I have tried to find the answer using the "Help" function in RStudio and using Google, but I'm guessing that my search terms are too vague. Could anyone help refresh my memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns is called `L1(s)` you may try:

```r
library(dplyr)
NJSBio = filter(biography, grepl("NJS.*", `L1(s)`))
```

Or adapting the last of your options

```r
NJSBio = subset(biography, grepl("NJS.*", biography$`L1(s)`))
```

should also work.

But to avoid problems and as a more general comment, it is better to avoid thhe use of parentheses in variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I attempted that and received the following:

// NJSBio = filter(biography, grepl("NJS.*", L1(s)))
Error in L1(s) : could not find function "L1" //

Could it be the parentheses in the column name causing an issue? It's the fourth column in the dataframe and the only column which has parentheses.

Comment: @HarryCaulton I have updated my answer. If you use the parentheses, write backticks `\`` around the variable name

Comment: Thank you. I realised why it didn't work. I still don't know which apostrophe you used ( I tried ' and " but couldn't find the ones in your message) but when I copied those apostrophes in your example individually, it worked! Thank you for your help

Edit in response to reply I didn't see while typing: Ohh so it's called a backtick, thank you for your comment!

Comment: @HarryCaulton You are welcome. If the answer has solved your question you may accept it.